# Two sample T test results

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, p-value

This is a result of my two sample t test, I understand if my sample difference lies between the 95% confidence interval, ideally my P value should not be less than 0.05. Following is my t test result in R. And here my p value is less than 0.05 despite of difference lies in confidence Interval. How's it possible ?

```
Two Sample t-test

data:  sample1 and sample2
t = 2.8194, df = 398, p-value = 0.005051
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
1.522659 8.537341
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
33.965    28.935
```

Please help to understand

Comment: You have it backwards, your central estimate will always lie within the confidence interval in this situation. Can you edit your question to clarify what the problem is for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 95% confidence interval does always include the empirical difference. The p-value is indeed related to the confidence interval: If the confidence interval includes 0, the p-value is greater than 0.05.

Since your confidence interval doesn't include 0, your p-value is small. With this result, you have statistical evidence against the null hypothesis (no difference between group means).